# encrypt single column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

Is this good practice to encrypt column without creating symmetric key.

```
create table EmpDetail(emp_id int,emp_name varchar(50), salary varbinary(100))
select * from EmpDetail

create view vw_EmpDetail as SELECT emp_id,emp_name,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('RS',salary))AS Salary FROM EmpDetail 
select * from vw_EmpDetail
```

Comment: If I were looking to hide the salary, I'd simply not include it in the view at all.

Comment: What is the point of creating this view?  Did you encrypt the salary using the passphrase `RS` before creating the view?

Comment: The biggest problem with this is that there's no salt (what `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` calls the "authenticator") -- equal salaries are encrypted equally, so you can know what class of salary someone's in even if you can't read off the plaintext, and worse, if you can update salaries you can just give yourself a raise by copying a value from someone that you know has a higher salary. Also, obviously, a phrase like `RS` is too short to be secure.